# Double Left Joins Ignoring Filter

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with visits, another with customers and another with locations (where each one belongs to).

I want to display the count on visits on each location. The desired results would be:

```
visit_count |  location_name
-----------------------------
     27     |   location_1
     1      |   location_2
     0      |   location_3
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(visits.visit_date) as visit_count, locations.location_name FROM locations 
LEFT JOIN VISITS ON locations.location_name = visits.location_checkin
LEFT JOIN customer ON visits.cust_id = customer.cust_id
WHERE locations.group_id = 1 AND customer.adm = false AND customer.super_adm = false
GROUP BY locations.id
```

But the result only gives me:

```
visit_count |  location_name
-----------------------------
     27     |   location_1
     1      |   location_2
```

It's the correct data, but erases the location with zero visits. I tried putting the
`customer.adm = false and customer.super_adm = false` on the left join on customer, but that list all three locations but ignores the filtering of the false statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move condition to `ON` clasue:

```
SELECT COUNT(customer.cust_id) as visit_count, locations.location_name 
FROM locations 
LEFT JOIN VISITS ON locations.location_name = visits.location_checkin 
LEFT JOIN customer ON visits.cust_id = customer.cust_id 
      AND customer.adm = false 
      AND customer.super_adm = false
WHERE locations.group_id = 1 
GROUP BY locations.id, locations.location_name -- here added location_name to match SELECT
```

If you use `WHERE` on outer table column reference it will work as normal `INNER JOIN`

Comment: This works to give me the locations, but ignores the fact of filter the counting with the ```customer.ads = false and the customer.super_adm = false``` So it doesn't return the desired results

Comment: it returns 35 for the 1st location, 1 for the second one and 0 for the third one, when it should be 27 for the first one, 1 for the second one and 0 for the third one

Comment: @MCM Easy to fix: `SELECT COUNT(customer.cust_id) as visit_count`

Comment: THIS DID THE TRICK!! ( changing the count to customer.cust_id)Thank you so much!! I was thinking about this for 2 hours and it was driving me crazy! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using left join  you  should not use left table columns in where  ..  (this work as an inner join  )
instead add  these condition to the related  on clause

```
SELECT COUNT(visits.visit_date) as visit_count, locations.location_name 
FROM locations 
LEFT JOIN VISITS ON locations.location_name = visits.location_checkin
LEFT JOIN customer ON visits.cust_id = customer.cust_id  
       AND customer.adm = false AND customer.super_adm = false
WHERE locations.group_id = 1 
GROUP BY locations.id
```

Comment: This works to give me the locations, but ignores the fact of filter the counting with the ```customer.ads = false and the customer.super_adm = false``` So it doesn't return the desired results

Comment: update your question and add  a coherent data sample

Comment: it returns 35 for the 1st location, 1 for the second one and 0 for the third one, when it should be 27 for the first one, 1 for the second one and 0 for the third one

Comment: It was an example that it was not filtering correctly, but just changing the count to customer.cust_id did the trick! Thanks!